# Updating Python Package with setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I maintain a Python Package on PyPI and I am having trouble testing changes. I would like to install it on my own computer and test before updating my version on PyPI. I try to run “python setup.py install” but it doesn’t reflect the changes that I have made. The only way I have been able to get it to reflect changes is to upload it to PyPI and update it with pip. Is there anyway to update using the setup.py? Or anyway to install on my computer before uploading to PyPI? I would assume there has to be but I have not been able to find anything for it yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use editable installs with pip to install from your source and have it update as you make changes:

```
$ pip install -e .
```

Comment: This approach creates the `egg`  but does not create a subdirectory of the package name under `site-packages`: so can not see the python sources. Why is that - and how can the source also be installed?